# How can I reset the grid rotation in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, grids

For some reason the grid got tilted in my Illustrator. Now everything has this tilted grid, even when I open new projects. I can't find anything online.

Any clue what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Hi Kevin, have you tried resetting Illustrator preferences back to default?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the rotation in:

- **Edit → Preferences → General...**

  Set Constrain Angle to 0°